# Hibernate manyToMany with extra columns

Tags: hibernate

I have trouble with Hibernate and manyToMany relationship with extra-columns, below my code:

```
@Entity
public class TransactionEntity extends AbstractBaseEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long transactionId;
  
  /* some fields*/

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "transaction", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<TransactionTagEntity> tags;
}

@Entity
public class TagEntity extends AbstractBaseEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long tagId;

  /* some fields*/

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tag", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<TransactionTagEntity> transactions;
}

@Entity
public class TransactionTagEntity extends AbstractBaseEntity {
  @EmbeddedId
  private TransactionTagPk pk;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("transactionId")
  private TransactionEntity transaction;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("tagId")
  private TagEntity tag;
}

@Embeddable
public class TransactionTagPk implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "transaction_id")
  private Long transactionId;

  @Column(name = "tag_id")
  private Long tagId;
}
```

When I try to select a transacton linked to a tag (or a tag linked to a transaction) I received this error:

```
Unknown column 't2_0.tag_tag_id' in 'on clause'
```

OR

```
Unknown column 't2_0.transaction_transaction_id' in 'on clause'
```

Where I've defined this columns?

### Edit

Below an example of query generated by Hibernate:

```
select t1_0.transaction_transaction_id, t1_0.tag_tag_id, t2_0.tag_id, t2_0.name, t2_0.note, t2_0.time_create, t2_0.time_update, t2_0.user_create_id, t2_0.user_id, t2_0.user_update_id, t1_0.time_create, t1_0.time_update, t1_0.user_create_id, t1_0.user_update_id from transaction_tag t1_0 left join tag t2_0 on t2_0.tag_id=t1_0.tag_tag_id where t1_0.transaction_transaction_id=?
```

Comment: Could you add a sample Hibernate query?

Comment: Added in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where I've defined this columns?

Short answer, you haven't defined this column name. More precisely you haven't defined column names except in the PK class.

I you don't define explicit column (or table) names Hibernate will do, based on different naming strategies.
Here is an awesome article: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-physical-naming-strategy/

In this case Hibernate will generate the following column names

```sql
create table TransactionTagEntity (
    transaction_transactionId bigint not null,
    tag_tagId bigint not null,
    primary key (tag_tagId, transaction_transactionId)
)
```

Using `@JoinColumn` annotation in `TransactionTagEntity` you can specify desired column names.

```java
@Entity
public class TransactionTagEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    public TransactionTagPk pk;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("transactionId")
    @JoinColumn(name="explicit_transaction_id",referencedColumnName = "transactionId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public TransactionEntity transaction;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("tagId")
    @JoinColumn(name="explicit_tag_id", referencedColumnName = "tagId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public TagEntity tag;
}
```

Now, Hibernate using the following column names

```sql
create table TransactionTagEntity (
    explicit_tag_id bigint not null,
    explicit_transaction_id bigint not null,
    primary key (explicit_tag_id, explicit_transaction_id)
)
```

Finally, I strongly recommend to always specify table, column names on entities.